# Cannot create a new DB on PostgreSQL in a Bitnami Django machine

Tags: linux, postgresql

I've installed a Bitnami image for Django (on ubuntu).

It comes preconfigured with PostgresSQL, which already has a "bitnami" user defined.

Now I want to create a new db, but `createdb` fails with:

```
createdb.bin: database creation failed: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

Sudo doesn't help...

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin/createdb -U bitnami new-db
```

I have no idea if there's a "postgres" user (usually the admin user), or what its password is...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this link](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/PostgreSQL#What_is_the_default_configuration.3f) you can find some documentation about the default configuration of PostgreSQL in [BitNami](http://www.bitnami.org). In the Virtual Machines the default password for the `'postgres'` database user is `'bitnami'`